# Отображение XPS в браузере

Tags: pdf, браузер, конвертация

Уже давольно продолжительное время бьюсь над задачей.

1. Есть REST API на C# (net6.0) в котором реализована возможность отправки файла по запросу из системы документооборота. Файл отправляется в виде массива байт и названия.
2. Есть портал на Python (Django). Функционал портала при нажатии на некий объект должен запрашивать файл из API и отображать на стороне клиента.
   Файлы могут быть xps или pdf.
   Проблема в том, что в системе документооборота файлы в основном хранятся в формате XPS.Для отображения я использую iframe. С отображением pdf это получается отлично. Но xps просто скачивается.
   Что я пробовал:

1. Искать js библиотеки способные отображать xps на стороне клиента. Таких не нашёл.
2. Конвертировать xps в pdf на стороне API. Частично это получилось. Но при первой итерации оказалось что я воспользовался платной библиотекой у которой пробный период 30 дней. Цена в 400$ в месяц слишком дорого для данного проекта. При второй итерации нашел проект Notan Jhones. Данная библиотека конвертирует не все файлы. И написана под net6.0-windows из-за чего у меня возникли трудности с созданием докер контейнера. Да и она не полностью покрывает потребности.
3. Пробовал реализовать эту задачу на Python. Но тоже не получилось.
   Как можно решить данную задачу и с какой стороны подойти.
   P.s. Использовать сторонние ресурсы или апи для конвертации или отображения нельзя так как документы могут быть коммерческие, что не безопасно...